# Can i7 4770 take 2 GPUs?

Tags: gpu, pci-express, intel-core-i7, multiple-users, dual-gpu

I want to use 2 AMD Radeon HD5450 GPUs and a Intel i7 4770 for a multi-seat gaming setup. I have found a motherboard that has 2 PCIe x16 ports ports but I am wondering if the CPU will support it because according to Intel's site it supports only 16 PCIe lanes but this is at PCI 3.0 spec while the GPUs use PCI 2.1. Any idea if it will work?

Comment: which do you want to use such low end GPUs? Buy a Radeon R280x instead of those both cards.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I want to do a multiseat setup with xen and will therefore need two separate GPUs for both user to have graphics, otherwise only one guy will have graphics, it will be good graphics but only for one guy...